# Ember Textfield binding when setting the value with JavaScript

Tags: ember.js

I've got some textfields set as follows

```
{{ input type="text" name="lat" value=event.latitude }}
```

This textfield value is set dynamically by a jQuery map plugin.  Whilst the value is set correctly, the binding to event.latitude is not being updated.  I'm assuming this is because the onChange event hasn't been fired, so Ember isn't updating the model binding.

I'm certain there are many hacked ways of doing this, but I'd like to know what's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Can you bind the value to `event`? I'm pretty sure that needs to be bound to an observable and/or computable object property... Can you post the view and controller you're using to represent `event`?

Comment: Can you show the code where you set the value with the jQuery map plugin?

Comment: It's the geocomplete plugin http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/. I've so far managed to get around the issue by binding to the geocode:result event and triggering a 'change' event on the affected inputs